# Trouble getting WordPress shortcode to display contents of file

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I'm trying to create a simple plugin to run a script and display associated html form using a shortcode. I've has no problem registering the script, but cannot get the shortcode to display the file contents. Here's what I have:

```
/* Add function and shortcode */
function my_function(){
    $options = wp_remote_retrieve_body( wp_remote_get( plugins_url() . '/my_plugin/my_file.html' ) );
}
add_shortcode('my-shortcode', 'my_function');
```

Thanks!

Comment: Great! That actually seems to work... any further comments on whether this is WP clean code would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The shortcode function is missing the return value. You're doing everything in one go, but I'd break it up as follows:

- `plugins_url()` is normally built with `/internal-path/file.ext`, and `__FILE__` that grabs our plugin folder name.
- is nice to test if `wp_remote_get()` actually worked using `is_wp_error()`.
- you're probably using it only for testing, but try to always give unique names to your functions

Final code:

```
add_shortcode( 'my-shortcode', 'shortcode_so_23113289' );

function shortcode_so_23113289(){
    $body = '';
    $response = wp_remote_get( plugins_url( '/my_file.html', __FILE__ ) );
    if( ! is_wp_error( $response ) )
    {
        $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );
    }
    return $body;
}
```